# How to format section* etc?

Tags: sectioning

I can change the format of sections and parts etc. with:

```
\titleformat{\section}{\LARGE\bfseries}{\thesection.}{0.5em}{}
```

However I cannot do the same for section* etc., I have tried this and it doesn't work:

```
\titleformat{\section*}{\LARGE\bfseries}{\thesection.}{0.5em}{}
```

Is this possible? I use Overleaf if that makes any difference.

Comment: As always on this site please provide a full but minimal example that others can copy and test as is. Then we also know which class and packages you are using

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Simply use `\titleformat{name=\section, numberless}{\LARGE\bfseries}{}{}{}`. Your code doesn't work beause `\thesection` doesn't exist for a starred section.